# How many different $3$-digit numbers can be formed if the digits $1$, $2$, $2$, $3$, $4$ are placed on separate cards?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Any suggestion on solving this problem to get rid of double/over counting?

The digits $1$, $2$, $2$, $3$, and $4$ are placed on separate cards.  How many different $3$-digit numbers can be formed by arranging the cards?

I tried...
 the case where all the numbers are distinct....like $1,2,3,4,5$ to make $3$-digit # and that is $5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 =  60$ possibilities. Now I need to correct for over counting as $2$ is a repeated digit.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Consider cases:

*Three different numbers are used*:  There are four ways to select the hundreds digit, three ways to select the tens digit, and two ways to select the units digit.  Hence, there are $4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 = 24$ such numbers.

*Two different numbers are used*:  There must be a repeated $2$.  Choose two of the three positions for the two $2$s.  Choose one of the other three digits for the free position.  There are $\binom{3}{2}\binom{3}{1} = 9$ such numbers.

*Total*:  Since the two cases above are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, there are $24 + 9 = 33$ three-digit numbers that can be formed with the given digits.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have $\color{red}{2}$ and $\color{blue}{2}$, so that 2s are distinct. Every solution with a 2 in it has a corresponding solution where red and blue are swapped. These pairs of solutions should be considered the same; this will get rid of double-counting.

So, to avoid double-counting, you need to add up (1) the number of solutions without any twos, plus (2) half the number of solutions containing twos.

There are $3! = 6$ solutions that don't contain twos, and there are $60-6=54$ solutions containing twos. Hence the correct number of solutions, avoiding double-counting, is:

$$6 + \frac{1}{2}(54) = 6 + 27 = 33$$